# Black on white in OS X fullscreen console mode

Tags: macos, console

Is it possible to configure the full screen console (the one you get by typing >console into the login window) so that it is black characterson a white background? Can this be done by setting the TERM variable to an appropriate value? I'm using OS X Leopard.